# Overriding functionality with modules in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

Without getting into the details of *why*, I'm looking for a clean (as possible) way to replace kernel functions and system calls from a loadable module.  My initial idea was to write some code to override some functions, which would take the original function (perhaps, if possible, *call* the function), and then add some of my own code.  The key is that the function that I write has to have the name of the original function, so other code, upon trying to access it, will access mine instead.

I can easily (comparatively) do this directly in the kernel by just throwing my code into the appropriate functions, but I was wondering if anyone knew a little C magic that isn't *necessarily* horrible kernel (or C) coding practice that could achieve the same result.

Thoughts of #defines and typedefs come to mind, but I can't quite hack it out in my head.

In short: does anyone know a way to effectively override functions in the Linux kernel (from a module)?

EDIT: Since it's been asked, I essentially want to log certain functions (creating/deleting directories, etc.) *from within the kernel*, but for sanity's sake, a loadable module seems to make sense, rather than having to write a big patch to the kernel code and recompile on every change.  A minimal amount of added code to the kernel is okay, but I want to offload most of the work to a module.

Comment: Can you clarify which one of these three you're trying to do:
1) Override calls to kernel functions from existing kernel code
2) Override calls to kernel functions from your kernel module
3) Override system calls in userspace that call into the kernel

Unless its #1, I'd recommend using #defines

Comment: 1 and 2?  I want to make the calls in the kernel itself to remain intact, just the functions that are being called (in the kernel) to be replaced by functions defined in my module.  If that makes *any* sense.

Comment: Not really, it would probably help if you explained the "why" part.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a very thin wrapper around system calls. This isn't considered good practice, but for some use cases, it would work.

Comment: Well kind of, except I need to take actions *before* the system calls complete, not after.

Comment: yea, and hooking system calls would let you do that, typically you you replace the system call with: int new_open(/* params */) { do_my_thing(/* params */); return old_open(/*params*/); }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realise that the question is three years old, but for the benefit of other people trying to do this sort of thing, the kernel has an interface called [kprobes](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kprobes.txt) to do just what you needed.

Comment: I just spent a few minutes looking into this, and I wonder how the hell I (or anyone else) never found this three years ago. Looks to be about right. I haven't gone and used and tested this, but since it seems to fit what I was looking for, I'll go ahead and mark this as correct!

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to [hook the system calls](http://rtg.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/docs/da-sa-txt/sa-dienelt.pdf) (PDF link), which would effectively let you log user-processes calling kernel functions. If you really want to log the *kernel* use of kernel functions, you want to look into [kernel function trace](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Function_Trace).

Comment: The one butchered by the markdown parser. Thanks for noticing; fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to do, but I think that [ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/) may be a good solution.  It's still under development, so I don't know if it's in any sort of usable condition right now.

Comment: What I'm looking at doesn't really have to do with reloading the kernel as much as modularizing my code within the kernel, and avoiding making changes to the existing code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at deploying your function using LD_PRELOAD?

Your function would be deployed via a shared lib that would live in a directory that is specified by the environment variable LD_PRELOAD.

The convention is that you intercept system calls and then, after performing your magic, pass the call onto the actual system shlib. But you don't have to do that.

Maybe take a look at the article "[Building library interposers for fun and profit](http://www.itworld.com/UIR000929interposers)". While it is Solaris specific, it is also applicable to Linux.

BTW This is how most memory analysis tools, e.g. Purify, work.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of work done in the kernel to make sure this does not happen, especially work to not expose the syscall table to modules. The only supported mechanism to log file access is [LSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules), but it is oriented towards security and has an uncertain [future](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Linux_Security_Modules_Sans_Modules). [Here](http://www.kroah.com/linux/talks/ols_2002_lsm_paper/lsm.pdf) is a PDF that documents the API, but it may not be up to date.

inotify is a much better way to monitor the creation, deletion and modification of files than trying to subvert the kernel syscall functions, but it works from userspace.

Quoted from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify):
Some of the events that can be monitored for are:

```
* IN_ACCESS - read of the file
* IN_MODIFY - last modification
* IN_ATTRIB - attributes of file change
* IN_OPEN and IN_CLOSE - open or close of file
* IN_MOVED_FROM and IN_MOVED_TO - when the file is moved or renamed
* IN_DELETE - a file/directory deleted
* IN_CREATE - a file/directory created
* IN_DELETE_SELF - file monitored is deleted
```

inotify exists in the kernel since 2.6.13, its predecesor is dnotify (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnotify).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [audit](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) for that

Comment: +1, the audit system will enable the OP to do what they intend... entirely from userspace.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blinkeye.ch/dokuwiki/doku.php/projects/lkm) might prove a useful read to you.

Basically, since the system call table is not directly exported in newer kernels, you have to do some searching to determine its location yourself. Then you can intercept your system calls of choice and manipulate them. Replacing other kernel functions, though, will be much more difficult, unless some of them are organized the same way system calls are (they appear on some dispatch table etc.) - which is not at all common.

Answer (score 0):

Most filesystem work is done in modules already, presuming that the filesystem code was built as a module, rather than built into the kernel (which means the 'real' answer depends on kernel build options).

Assuming that the bits you want to log are all filesystem-related, and that those filesystem routines are built as modules, you should just be able to alter the filesystem module(s) you're interested in, and reload them.

If those assumptions aren't true, or can't be made true, then things clearly get trickier, and I really couldn't point you much further.

Comment: Interesting take, though ideally I'd be logging at a higher level than the particular filesystem (like sys_write or vfs_write).  I figure doing it at that level would make my code filesystem-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to only log the calls (i.e. you will not actually override them), and a small amount of changes to the kernel code is acceptable, the cleanest way would be to add a hook to each function you are interested in (using a notifier chain or even a plain function pointer). Your module then simply registers itself to all the hooks you added (and unregisters from them when unloaded).

It is also quite possible that someone else has already done the work of adding the hooks for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to modify existing system calls, you want to instrument them. This is what [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) is for. If you really want to do it the hard way and intercept system calls by coding your own module, I suggest you read some rootkit literature but I don't have any link handy (although phrack comes to mind).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x978.html

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that method is no longer possible as of 2.6.  sys_call_table[] is no longer exported.

Answer (score 0):

According to KernelTrap.org [you can do a simple patch](http://kerneltrap.org/node/4010) and recompile of your kernel to export the sys_call_table variable:

```
// add the following in the file arch/i386/kernel/i386_ksyms.c
extern void* sys_call_table[];
EXPORT_SYMBOL(sys_call_table);
```

Then just follow [this procedure for replacing system calls](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x978.html) from the Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide:

> The source code here is an example of
>   such a kernel module. We want to 'spy'
>   on a certain user, and to `printk()` a
>   message whenever that user opens a
>   file. Towards this end, we replace the
>   system call to open a file with our
>   own function, called `our_sys_open`.
>   This function checks the uid (user's
>   id) of the current process, and if
>   it's equal to the uid we spy on, it
>   calls `printk()` to display the name of
>   the file to be opened. Then, either
>   way, it calls the original `open()`
>   function with the same parameters, to
>   actually open the file.
>
> The `init_module` function replaces the
>   appropriate location in `sys_call_table`
>   and keeps the original pointer in a
>   variable. The `cleanup_module` function
>   uses that variable to restore
>   everything back to normal. This
>   approach is dangerous, because of the
>   possibility of two kernel modules
>   changing the same system call. Imagine
>   we have two kernel modules, A and B.
>   A's `open` system call will be `A_open`
>   and B's will be `B_open`. Now, when A is
>   inserted into the kernel, the system
>   call is replaced with `A_open`, which
>   will call the original `sys_open` when
>   it's done. Next, B is inserted into
>   the kernel, which replaces the system
>   call with `B_open`, which will call what
>   it thinks is the original system call,
>   `A_open`, when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If the shared libraries call a system call, you are going ot make a module that alters that sysltem call. For more information on altering system calls, you might want to look here
http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/
there is something in there in how they change what the open() system calls.
An example is here
http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/x931.html