# Replacing a kernel function by using loadable kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to replace a kernel function with a kernel module, and come across the following solusion proposed by kmm (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242232/6438341)

However, it seems that the kernel does not allow copying anything to the address of 'real_printk'. The kernel complains: "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffff81774863", in which ffffffff81774863 is the address of printk that was found in System.map or /proc/kallsyms.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say it's probably because you're running a kernel that write-protects its text pages. You will need to set those pages as writable before modifying them.

**HOWEVER**, keep in mind that that answer you're looking at is six years old. In the time since it was posted, a number of much better approaches to live kernel patching have emerged, including [kpatch](https://github.com/dynup/kpatch), [SUSE Live Patching](https://www.suse.com/products/live-patching), and [KernelCare](https://cloudlinux.com/all-products/product-overview/kernelcare). (Underneath, there's also [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt), which can be used to dynamically instrument functions.) You should take a close look at these before trying to build your own patching solution from scratch.