# Intercepting 64-bit Linux kernel function: Length of a function pointer at 32/64-bit?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, interception

I'm trying to re-implement old-as-behemoth kernel intercept (described at [this Phrack issue](http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=59&id=14#article)).

The code to replace 32-bit function call is like:

```
#define SYSMAPADDR 0x12345678
#define CODESIZE 7
static char acct_code[7] = "\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00"/*movl $0, %eax*/
"\xff\xe0";/*jmp *%eax*/
*(long*)&acct_code[1] = (long)my_hijacking_function;
// here, use either set_pages_rw or trick CR0 to do this:
memcpy(SYSMAPADDR, acct_code, CODESIZE);
```

But 64-bit address of original function is 0xffffffff12345678 (kernel is located in low-memory).

So will the *(long)* new function pointer fit just 4 *\x00* bytes of the *movl* instruction?

*Btw, please link this to [Can I replace a Linux kernel function with a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196944/can-i-replace-a-linux-kernel-function-with-a-module) and [Overriding functionality with modules in Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290898/overriding-functionality-with-modules-in-linux-kernel), the hacky method described above is more flexible (can intercept non-extern functions => no need to recompile the kernel).*

Comment: This Phrack issue is quite outdated. The 2.6.3x Linux kernel is quite different to 2.4.x - so I doubt anything from this issue will work with current kernels. Also syscalls are organized differently, to allow for the fast syscall facility of modern CPUs.

Comment: @datenwolf, it works with some modifications - http://memset.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/syscall-hijacking-kernel-2-6-systems/ - just trying to fix it for 64-bit.

Comment: thanks to jmkeyes and Random832, going to set up a group of tests on chosen 32/64-bit distros with different 2.4-2.6 kernels (up to current). Meanwhile, want more ideas.. :) this is one rep-consuming bounty.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to make a direct and unconditional jump to an address with a displacement greater than 2GB on any x86 (32 or 64 bit).

When I wrote a detouring library some time ago, the best options I could come up with to redirect program flow (for x86-64) involved backing up the target function's prologue by `M` bytes and overwriting the target function's prologue with two instructions.

I use the *%r11* register instead of the accumulator. According to the [AMD64 ABI Draft 0.99.5](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), *%r11* is a temporary register that is not preserved across function calls.

The first instruction, `movq $addr, %r11`, does exactly what it looks like: it loads the specified address into a register. The second instruction, `jmp *%r11`, forces an unconditional indirect jump to the address stored in *%r11*.

Appended to the end of the backed-up instructions should be another unconditional indirect jump back to the original target's function, to an address immediately after the overwritten instructions. Then, when you want to call to original, you can invoke the address of the backed up function prologue and program flow continues as usual.

Remember that the number of bytes to backup, `M`, must be the sum of the size of the store/jump instructions and the remainder of the overwritten instruction. You don't want to leave any partial instructions behind after doing this voodoo.

Comment: Going to run a few experiments.. btw, 2GB limit is OK, because the kernel loads itself into lower memory, but still needs 64-bit addressing to function.

Comment: Storing an immediate into a register using `movq` is implicitly sign-extended, as detailed [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html).

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I am assuming this is for x86_64.*

Function pointers are 64 bits, and the `movl` instruction zero-extends into 64-bit registers, so you'll have to rewrite the machine code. The instruction you want is probably `48 B8 (imm64)` (i.e. `movq ..., %rax`), and I *think* the jump instruction can be left alone, but I don't know much about this. You should probably add the 'x86-64' and 'assembly' tags to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JMP rel32` (0xE9) operation to perform a 32-bit relative jump from the current address. This will allow you to make a jump to anywhere within 2GB of the source address in five bytes. It also has the advantage that it does not clobber %eax (this may or may not be important in your case).

That said, I would recommend looking into the [kprobes API](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kprobes.txt) instead. This handles all the hard work of runtime patching for you. It also deals with multiple markers being applied to the same function and other such nastiness, and is portable to multiple platforms. In particular, if your monkey-patching approach was in use, it could conflict with the markers API if compiled in, resulting in crashes. It would also result in crashes if dynamically patchable code was located in the first few bytes of a function (LOCK prefixes, etc).

You might also want to look into how [ftrace works](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) - depending on kernel configuration, it might be somewhat faster to hook into ftrace instead.

Comment: Heh, another deprecated (in favor of Tracepoints) API. "Starting then, kernel markers were slowly removed from kernel sources and eventually fully removed in Linux kernel 2.6.32[8][9], which was released on December 3, 2009.".

Comment: Also, it seems that adding new tracepoint/marker still needs the kernel code to be recompiled.

Comment: Sorry, I confused it with kprobes >_> I'll update my answer for the correct one.